# I am creating a Table setting Maxlength = 5 for a column and its created with length = 1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have the following table being created (by using DNX commands in EF7, now EF Core)

```
[Table("FishGrade")]
public partial class FishGrade
{
    public FishGrade()
    {
        FishPrices = new HashSet<FishPrice>();
    }

    [HiddenInput]
    [Column("FishGradeId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("GradeCode")]
    [MaxLength(5), Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Column("GradeName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FishPrice> FishPrices { get; set; }
}
```

But when it the table is created, the Code column (column named=GradeCode), is created as a 1 character long column.

I also have the following in the `OnModelCreating` method

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<FishGrade>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Code)
                .HasColumnType("char");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                .HasMaxLength(1)
                .HasColumnType("char");
        });
```

Why is this happening? How can I get the column to be created with length = 5?

Comment: I do have a lot of other tables and I probably another column somewhere called Code as well and it may be 1 char long

Comment: Why do you redefine in fluent API what you defined in attributes? You use `HasColumnType("char")` which basically says create a column of the char type which in turn can store one character - so is 1 character long. If you have to/want to use fluent api you probably should use something like `HasColumnType("char(5)")` to indicate that you want a string of 5 characters. I would however recommend to not overwrite the type if not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your model in three ways:

- conventions
- attributes
- fluent API

Conventions are applied first, then attributes, and finally the fluent API in your model builder. Your model builder is resetting the attribute configuration.

You should try to simplify your model configuration and use always the same method.

NOTE: take into account that, if you use something like MVC client side validation, it only understands the configuration made via attributes. In all other regards it doesn't mind how you configure your EF model.